# Is there a way to use git with multiple users on a shared computer?

Tags: git, version-control, linux, tools

I'm currently a user of a large research compute cluster which has many other users. We all have access to a shared program that is being actively developed and used. Since we are all effectively working on the same filesystem, I was wondering if there is a way to use git as though we each have our own copy of the repository (without actually doing that)?

The specific example I'm interested in is: how can two users have different branches checked out at the same
time (say if they want to test different features in development)?

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: @gnat I did... It seems like a "workflow" question to me: "If you are trying to figure out how to use git to do something, understanding the conceptual foundations of git, or how to identify and overcome a problem that you have with the workflow... These are questions for Softwareengineering.SE."

Comment: no. the git data is stored on the file system, so you would run into problems#

Comment: This is a place where git is really helpful, since all the tracking is stored in the folder itself you can just clone a local repository to a new folder and work in that folder, then push your changes upstream locally.

Answer (score 4):

Search for "git bare repositories". They are made exactly for this purpose. You need a directory that's write-accessible by all users, then you can push into this directory and pull/clone from it just as you would do with github or gitlab. Of course, it doesn't provide a nice web interface...

If you have a small web server that your group can use you might want to set up a [gogs](https://gogs.io/) or [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) site which offers more protection and a comfortable interface.